# Control ubuntu terminal from Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I want to write a routine that will automatically change my Machine learning parameters and execute the (Machine learning) code multiple times and save its result into a text file.

The Machine learning code is run from the Ubuntu terminal and its result also are written to the Ubuntu terminal.

I need a way to read data and write data to the Ubuntu terminal from the C++ code.

What I have found so far is the QProcess:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("gnome-terminal"); //THE TERMINAL IS OPENED INDEED
char w[] = "write";
process.write(w,sizeof(w));
process.waitForFinished();
```

But nothing is written or read from it

What does working is:

```
  QProcess process1;
  QProcess process2;
  process1.setStandardOutputProcess(&process2);
  process1.start("echo 0534230313");
  process2.start("sudo -S poweroff");
  process2.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
```

And also this works:

```
int result = system("echo 0534230313 | sudo -S poweroff"); ///COMMANDS TO TERMINAL
int result2 = system("gnome-terminal"); ///OPEN TERMINAL
```

But the problem is that I wont be able to read the output result (My Machine learning program can open and write to the terminal by itself)

Comment: Why is gnome-terminal involved here?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [finished](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#finished) signal to read the process output results

```
connect( poProcess, static_cast<void (QProcess::*)(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)>(&QProcess::finished),
         [=](int,QProcess::ExitStatus)
{
    QByteArray oProcessOutput=
            poProcess->readAllStandardOutput();

    // Parse the process output.
    //

    // Mark process for deletion.
    emit poProcess->deleteLater();
});
```

Comment: Ok and how do I start the process (so that the c++ program will know that the process started)? Or you mean that I can use the process.start methode and it will work with it?

Comment: Yes, use the start method, you also can connect to the [started](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#started) signal that indicate that the process has started.

Comment: @iliagildin, do you need any more help with this question?